# Change number format in MySQL (European format)

Tags: mysql, formatting

I need to change all the numbers in a field (type longtext), from `xxxxxx,yy` to `xxx.xxx,yy`

Being 'x' integers and 'y' decimal numbers.

Examples:

> 6000,00 to 6.000,00
>
> 100000,00 to 100.000,00

I've tried `format` but it changes a number from:

> xxxxxx,yy to xxx,xxx.yy

Example:

> 1200,00 to 1,200.00

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I have to use the current datatype, I'm not allowed to change it, it is not my decision. I already know that it's not the correct way to handle things.

What I need is something equivalent to this update:

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = FORMAT(<field>, 2, 'de_DE');
```

However this only works with MySQL 5.5 (because of the third parameter), and I only can do this in a machine that uses MySQL 5.1

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as text in the first place? In this case you should likely be using a [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) type. Region-specific formatting should be handled in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database is there to store and get you the data. Not to make it look pretty. Handle that somewhere else.

Update: Didn't see that you have stored it in a longtext column. As long as there is no important reason (I bet there is none) to keep it that way, the best and only answer is, that you should change the datatype of that column.

Update 2: If you insist...

```
create table lt(lt longtext);
insert into lt values ('6000,00'), ('1234567,12');
select 
lt,
replace(replace(replace(format(convert(replace(lt, ',', '.'), decimal(10,2)), 2), ',', 'x'), '.', ','), 'x', '.')
from lt
```

Update 3: If all will be `x,00` you can spare the convert and do it like this:

```
replace(replace(replace(format(lt, 2), ',', 'x'), '.', ','), 'x', '.')
```

Comment: Thanks!, it works like a charm. Fortunately I don't need precision in de decimals, (meaning, all will have ,00)